# ruby Grape Validation doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

I write `requires`,like this

```
params do
    requires :user_id, :type => Integer
    optional :page, :type => Integer, :default => 1
    optional :per_page, :type => Integer, :default => 20
end
```

and I have wrote `rescue_from`

```
rescue_from :all do |e|
  case e
  when Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors
    error!({ messages: e.full_messages }, 400)
  else
    Rails.logger.error "Api Error: #{e}"
    Rails.logger.error "#{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
    error!({ messages: "errors" }, 500)
  end
end
```

but I cannot catch `Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors` without `params[:user_id]`

Comment: What do you mean when you say `but it doesn't works for Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors`? What do you expect ?

Comment: I cannot catch Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors without params[:user_id], the Validation doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your code doesn't work, but I can offer another working solution: rescue validation errors explicitly (above the rescue_from :all).

```
rescue_from Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors do |e|
  error!({ messages: e.full_messages }, 400)
end

rescue_from :all do |e|
  Rails.logger.error "Api Error: #{e}"
  Rails.logger.error "#{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
  error!({ messages: "errors" }, 500)
end
```

Comment: `Started GET "/client/v4/addresses?user_id=-199999" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-19 00:28:59 +0800`
`Started GET "/client/v4/addresses" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-19 09:49:15 +0800` ,Nothing in log

Comment: Nothing to say. I will try to help you if you public and give me the link to the Grape source file that consists this code.

Comment: It‘s a mistake by myself, I write a method named 'fail'